# Redis и большие наборы данных

Tags: redis

При выполнении `sinter` 2х множеств по 50к элементов в каждом редис моментально закрывает соединение. То же самое происходит иногда при smembers множества из 50к элементов. в конфиге прописал `client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0` но это не помогает. Как избавить редис от разрыва коннекта при большом наборе данных?